# Esp8266 blue and red constantly on

Tags: android-wifi, arduino-uno, esp8266

Esp8266 is attached to my arduino uno. It was working fine. But then suddenly it started being disconnected from the network and also it doesn't connect to last connected wifi network by itself. Then after sometime when i was troubleshooting the problem, the blue led which was previously blinking is not constantly on and sending garbage on serial monitor. Can anyone help to restore it back. How can i get that blue led back to blinking?

Comment: Any logs? Description of what you've already done as part of *troubleshooting the problem*?

Comment: the code is about uploading the sensor data to thingspeak. Uptil now according to my searching i have found that may be flash chip has been damaged or may be firmware should be updated. Well, i havent updated the firmware uptill now.

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me too. After a lot of googling / trying I wrote a post [here](http://bbs.espressif.com/viewtopic.php?t=4597#p15844) to describe what I tried and how I fixed the issue.

I hope it helps somebody else!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're using ESP-12 module that has 2 leds,
the problem you're facing may be from a corrupted firmware.

Please try to re-flash it by ESP8266Flasher using follow configuration.

```
boot_v1.2+.bin      0x00000
user1.1024.new.bin  0x01000
blank.bin           0x7e000 & 0xfe000
```

esp8266 is sensitive to voltage spike, you need to add cap between VCC/GND
or this problem may re-occur again.

Please look more at this [article](http://internetofhomethings.com/homethings/?p=396).

English is not my native language, I'll try my best to help you out.

Comment: I have uploaded the firmware through this link http://www.agcross.com/2015/09/the-esp8266-wifi-chip-part-3-flashing-custom-firmware/ and have selected the Al-Thinker firmware..but now the blue led blinks only when it should. It is also giving Ok to AT commands but it gives error on some AT commands like 'AT+CWLAP', AT+CWJAP , when i try to connect to a network. Now what should i do? And also when the firmware was being update and it was 99% done in the end it said unable to leave flash mode.

Comment: Please try to change flash size to smaller size (eg 512k,4mbit) and try again if it still doesn't work you may need to get now one.

Comment: how can i change the flash size?